# CoreData Is there a disadvantage of storing a NSDate as a UTC-Timestamp?

Tags: iphone, core-data, types

in Sql there are date-functions, but in CoreData there are only "<","=" and similar.
If I store a Date as a intvalue representing the timestamp, I will be able to use "-","+" and similar too. 
Is there one benefit in storing a date as a NSDate besides converting ? I think not but I'm not sure.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no disadvantage. In fact, if you select "Use scalar properties for primitive data types" when you generate your NSManagedObject subclass, it will convert your NSDate to a NSTimeInterval (double) for you.